# How to use EDID when it occasionally returns wrong characters

Tags: edid

Folks,

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 minimal + openbox.

In our C-based application, the information can be displayed only on approved display devices. We rely on EDID to get the information for the connected display device.

Everything works as expected. However, occasionally EDID returns us some garbled characters. For example, `SAMSUNG` may come out as `SAMSyNG`.

The programming logic to obtain EDID information is straightforward. It makes me feel that EDID itself is not as reliable. I am wondering if anyone else has faced such a problem and what you have done programmatically to overcome the problem.

Thank you in advance for sharing your thoughts.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?